# Debug kernel panic - Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 9?

Tags: crash, sles

on a freshly reinstalled SLES 11.4 we see this dmesg from /var/crash:

```
<7>[   48.600847] storage: no IPv6 routers present
<6>[   63.725477] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 1 devices found
<6>[  310.226578] [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
<6>[ 3536.417543] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
<6>[ 3536.417582] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
<6>[ 3536.983736] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
<6>[ 3537.005660] Uniform Multi-Platform E-IDE driver
<6>[ 3537.011756] ide-cd driver 5.00
<6>[ 3537.033960] st: Version 20101219, fixed bufsize 32768, s/g segs 256
<0>[ 3691.340041] Kernel panic - not syncing: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 9
<4>[ 3691.447069] Pid: 0, comm: kworker/0:1 Tainted: G             X 3.0.101-107-default #1
<4>[ 3691.554690] Call Trace:
<4>[ 3691.590254]  [<ffffffff81004b35>] dump_trace+0x75/0x300
<4>[ 3691.664599]  [<ffffffff81467873>] dump_stack+0x69/0x6f
<4>[ 3691.738878]  [<ffffffff8146792f>] panic+0xb6/0x224
<4>[ 3691.804367]  [<ffffffff810c900c>] watchdog_overflow_callback+0xdc/0xe0
<4>[ 3691.896736]  [<ffffffff810f55fa>] __perf_event_overflow+0xaa/0x230
<4>[ 3691.980294]  [<ffffffff81018808>] intel_pmu_handle_irq+0x1a8/0x370
<4>[ 3692.069469]  [<ffffffff8146c8f1>] perf_event_nmi_handler+0x31/0xa0
<4>[ 3692.156027]  [<ffffffff8146ea47>] notifier_call_chain+0x37/0x70
<4>[ 3692.239630]  [<ffffffff8146ea8d>] __atomic_notifier_call_chain+0xd/0x20
<4>[ 3692.334749]  [<ffffffff8146eadd>] notify_die+0x2d/0x40
<4>[ 3692.409254]  [<ffffffff8146c073>] default_do_nmi+0x33/0xc0
<4>[ 3692.489610]  [<ffffffff8146c168>] do_nmi+0x68/0x80
<4>[ 3692.558033]  [<ffffffff8146b595>] restart_nmi+0x1e/0x2e
```

Reinstalled it to check that is it a hw or sw issue, but it still **crashes when we run a DSA log** (started at ~3500 sec uptime).

**The Question:** from this dmesg (or any other info) can we determine, what caused the crash? cpu9 error? or driver error maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like upgrading megaraid firmware (AND a ram dimm issue too!) fixed the crash during DSA.

Comment: hey, why did I got a "-1" ? :( why do people give "-1" without a comment? what did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your answer. All I can say is that for some reason somebody considered it to be "not useful". My guess is that the down-voter takes an extremist position (that questions-and-answers should always be useful to users other than the OP) - or that they think answers should be more substantial. I think short answers posted as comments are more of a problem for the site. Anyhow, welcome to [unix.se]. I hope your next interaction with its users is more constructive. Feel free to take the [tour] and browse the [help].